# what file structure should I use for django app on google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gcloud

I can't get my django app to run on google app engine.

It deploys successfully but throws an error when I try connect to it in my browser.

main.py throws the following error: from wsgi import application as app  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'

I've looked at the question here:

[ModuleNotFoundError - No module named 'main' when attempting to start service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52395695/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-main-when-attempting-to-start-service/52395801)

I don't know what file structure is 'expected' for my main.py to run without errors.

This is the current structure

```
              --static root file--main.py, app.yaml, etc.
              |
```

voting------------

```
              |
              --voting-----------settings.py, wsgi.py, etc.
              |
              other stuff
```

my main.py currently reads (voting is the name of my project)

from voting.wsgi import application as app

I have tried voting.voting.wsgi and wsgi also. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by moving the static root.

Look at this for an example of how to set out the folder structure and where to place the static root: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python37/django