# Django no module named 'main'

Tags: python, django

I was working on a Django project on my PC, Then I created an application named "register" and I get a weird error when I try to run manage.py runserver:
im using Python 3.8.3.
this error occurs when i added forms for registration.

```
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main    
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

my settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'simple2',
    "crispy_forms",
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    'register.apps.RegisterConfig',
    'register'
]
...
```

Comment: Did you enable venv?

Comment: it works before creating new app... i think the problem is sth different.

Comment: You can remove `'register'` from `INSTALLED_APPS` because you already have `'register.apps.RegisterConfig',`. If you don't have an app called `main`, then remove `'main.apps.MainConfig',`. If you do have an app called `main`, then please show the layout of your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you didn't configure your WSGI app as Django's App engine looks for an `app` variable in a file named `main.py`. Here are two ways you can look at this:

**Include your WSGI Application**

You still can create a file named `main.py` that includes an `app variable`. You don't need to write anything, just import it (let's say your project name is `projekt`:

```py
from projekt.wsgi import main as app
```

**Adding a custom entrypoint**

As in [Google's Appengine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref):

> `entrypoint`: Optional. The command that is executed when your app starts. For your app to receive HTTP requests, `entrypoint` should contain a command which starts a web server that listens on the port specified by the PORT environment variable. If you do not specify an `entrypoint`, App Engine will configure and start the Gunicorn webserver.

A comparison between the default  and your need:

```py
# default
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
# What you need
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT demosite.wsgi:main
```

More information on [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup). [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52395801).

Comment: where i must add  ``` from projekt.wsgi import main as app ```  and where create main.py?

Comment: You can try putting it on the same level as settings.py. It it doesn't work, go one level down into manage.py. Although keep in mind `projekt` should be replaced by your project name.

Comment: i did this and get this error please help me:
```
raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Comment: Will this thread help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55929118